# What kind of data type the "customer id" in Bank database could have? INT or VARCHAR?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

What kind of data type the "customer id" in Bank database could have? INT or VARCHAR? 
Considering that there is another table with "owner" attribute which is a foreign key for "customer id"

Comment: Try `BOOLEAN`...  Is this homework? No one should be touching a bank's database if they're asking SO this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no right answer to this.

Many organizations use alphanumeric sequences for customer id's, so that would need to be a varchar.

In other cases, they don't care what the software developer uses to form a primary key, so you might as well use an integer to take advantage of MySQL's builtin auto_increment feature (this works with integers but not with arbitrary strings).

So you should find out what your bank organization requires you to use as the customer id, if anything.

Or use an auto-increment integer, and plan to add a column for the bank's own customer id, which may be a string of some kind.

It's also not unusual for the data type of a customer id to change every few years, as someone gets the idea that it has to encode some information besides being unique.

Comment: Surely the 'volatile' key would be a natural key?  Leading to the use of a non-volatile surrogate key used by the database for the primary and foreign keys, etc?  I've never personally encountered a *valid* business need to encode information into and/or modify the value of a surrogate key...

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's "valid" by our definition. They will require it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Databases often have two unique identifiers for real life entities.

- The natural key
- The surrogate key

In your case, the natural key might be a string *(varchar)* corresponding to something the customer might see on a bank statement.  Potentially including parts of their name and/or date of birth.

Then, the surrogate key would normally be a unique Integer created by the database solely for the purposes of uniquely identifying the customer inside the database.  Because that surrogate key is smaller *(typically 4 bytes vs potentially dozens)*, its use in foriegn keys and indexes uses less disk space, memory, io, etc, and so generally would make the database more compact and run more smoothly / quickly.

This natural/surrogate key combination allows the surrogate key to fullfil ***only*** the role of uniquely identifying a row *(customer)*, and never changing.  Because, should it change, all rows that reference it from other tables *(foreign keys)*, would also need to change.  The natural key *can* change with time, because it only exists in the customer table, and the surrogate key is used everwhere else.